# I3 how to auto start (when i3 launches) tmux with irssi

Tags: tmux, i3

Every time i launch the computer i want an TMUX IRSSI window to be launched.

i3/conf:

```
exec --no-startup-id irc
```

irc script:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -n "IRC" -d 'irssi'
tmux -2 attach-session -d
```

so i know if i launch tmux manually i can get the script to work. (since tmux attaches new-session) but i couldn't find out how to exec tmux with irssi any other way.
my problem is doing without having to launch tmux manually.

i need tmux so i can use IRSSI, otherwise when someone /pm me it wont show up.